# HTML full responsive tips

Tags: html, responsive-design, responsive

**Well, I'm applying responsiveness to my little projects for learning purposes.**

I've looked at some websites like: [w3schools-mediaquery](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

I've found interesting things, but I'd like to know how to handle the various resolutions and which medium is most recommended for a full responsive website.

I currently have something like:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {}
```

basically to begin with a simple adaptation, without much work, I was thinking of starting with:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {}
@media only screen and (min-width: 650px) {}
@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {}
```

Would coding an interface `every 50px` be useful? `10 to 10, 20 to 20, 50 to 50` which would be the most recommended? or is there another more useful way to do this?

I would like to do everything manually, bootstrap is a distant alternative.

> Some examples, recommendations, and corrections are welcome!

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: using 50px steps will render you a huge and unmaintainable css file. Can't you use Bootstrap? If not, why not go with their media screen steps? They work pretty well for most cases.

Comment: Aside from their native steps I usually create a "XXL" and a "3XL" for larger screens than 1200px wide. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints

Comment: The problem by using default steps, an ex: 

`max-width: 600px` for this resolution the responsivity is perfect, but resolutions smaller than this will generate small visual bugs.

And the same thing for `min-width: 1200px` which after exceeding 1200 will also cause visual bugs.

How i can fix this small problems?

Comment: that is exactly the chalenge (and that's why I'm suggesting you to use Bootstrap if possible). Those steps will roughly map to some of the most commons devices (like phones, tablets, mid-res computers and hi-res computer - specially if you add the xxl and 3xl as I do). Then, you could play HIDE and SHOW (not the best way to go) or, really spend some time on figuring how to best display everything on smaller resolutions (for that, Bootstrap's - or any other - GRID SYSTEM will help you a lot!).

Comment: Can you include a simple page of your project on your question? Maybe I can show you some examples on it (but use a very simple one, ok?)

Comment: @MarceloMyara I've solved the problem, with the help of Ron Royston and these websites: [Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp) [box-sizing Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp) The example given on these websites is not exactly a grids system, but it's similar! Anyway, thanks for your reply!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I use a single breakpoint, basically I'm detecting phones only. As far as overall layout, I'm using CSS Grid as it is most capable. I find that several breakpoints is unrealistic to maintain and so I no longer consider tablet views. It's either a phone view or not a phone view.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {

}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {

}
```

Comment: So you limit the page to just one resolution (phones)? in this case, any other resolution will reproduce visual bugs? Anyway, I liked this idea, thanks!

Comment: 2. phones and desktop/tablets/anything else. Two.

Comment: I would only write a media query for "desktop/tablets/anything else". Write phone styles as the default (a.k.a. mobile-first), and then override for larger screens.

Comment: You end up writing most of your CSS above the `@media` queries as only a few elements need to vary depending on phone vs other viewports.